# heroku app on firefox won't load javascripts due to content security policy

Tags: javascript, ruby, heroku, sinatra, content-security-policy

I have a new app deployed to heroku. On chrome it works as expected but in firefox I get the following error (and more like it) in the console:

`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).`

It's not just an annoyance - since it's blocking the javascripts from loading, the site is basically not usable on FF which is obviously quite problematic.  I can't modify the headers on heroku as my research has suggested.

What do?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your content security policy in your `Rails` app layer itself so no Heroku config changes are needed as follows:

```rb
# config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb

Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.default_src :self, :https
  policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
  policy.img_src     :self, :https, :data
  policy.object_src  :none
  policy.script_src  :self, :https
  policy.style_src   :self, :https, :unsafe_inline
  policy.report_uri  "/csp-violation-report-endpoint"
end
```

You can change this as needed. and more details can be found [here](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/10/23/rails-5-2-adds-dsl-for-configuring-content-security-policy-header.html)

Comment: thanks! I'm using sinatra, but i guess there must be a similar configuration option available